# Benchmarking xv6 new process scheduler

Tags: benchmarking

I have implemented a new scheduler for the xv6 OS, but I don't know how to measure the performance of this new one. I found one benchmark to measure the time, but will the benchmarks for Unix work well on xv6? any ideas...

Comment: xv6 is a *nix alright.  But scheduler perfomance is something pretty hard to measure.  I'd start with an attempt using a VM.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean "start an attempt using VM". I'm running xv6 over qemu. I found someone who talked about uptime() system call, but not sure if this the way?

Comment: Cool, yeah, that will be good enough.  What I mean by difficult to measure is that a scheduler dealt with timing and therefore measuring the timings is particularly difficult.  In other words **there is no single timing that has a good meaning of performance**.  How quick it is to perform process switch?  When there are several process to assign in the queue does it take the first or there is some form of priority (aka realtime processing)?  Is the priority respected always?  Does the priority help in random scenarios?  Or it hinders the overall time?